# CSS dynamic multiple teir dropdown menu

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I recently began attempting to develop a simple Wordpress theme for myself, and have since hit a wall with the navigation menu.

The drop down menu will have multiple items and multiple sub menus with the need to add more in the future. Example from the default Wordpress theme - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKJwX.png

I wanted to know what kind of CSS was behind the menu being able to dynamically add another item and sub menu with no limit.

Thanks

Comment: CSS2/3 :-) Seriously, there are dozens of examples of this on the web,  just google dropdown menu css

Comment: The dropdown menu part is fine, I wanted to know the CSS to essentially allow adding unlimited sub menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover  > ul{
  display: block;
}
​
```

HTML:

```
​<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>
        Item 3
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 3.1</li>
            <li>Subitem 3.2</li>
            <li>
                Subitem 3.3
                <ul>
                    <li>Subitem 3.3.1</li>
                    <li>Subitem 3.3.2</li>
                    <li>Subitem 3.3.3</li>
                </ul>                    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/TKBdY/

Comment: Thanks! Anyway to make that styling dynamic too?

Comment: That is dynamic, it can have list after list after list added and it will work. The > says "next one only, not before, not after, next one only"

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen, only the third node is a dropdown.

Comment: `ul li` selects all `li` descendents of `ul` (son, grandson). `ul > li`, selects only the `li` children of `ul` (direct child). See more: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html

Comment: I noticed that, but the submenu will disappear when you hover on that.